# Do subsequent Unlocked Package version installs deploy FLS?

Tags: profile, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, package-install, fls

I've created an Unlocked Package using Salesforce CLI and installed the first version in an org. I've checked the Field Level Security for each Profile and they were all correct. But when I changed the FLS for a profile and made another package version for that same package, the FLS simply wasn't being updated after installing this new version in that org. 
So far I managed to update the FLS for subsequent versions by using metadata-api to deploy all the profiles to the org. But that just doesn't feel right.
Am I missing something that I should have been doing?